# Classify singularities - Hint

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

I tried for a while to classifiy the singularities of $\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{\sin z}$ at the origin, but I am stucked. Is there someone who is able to help me at this point?

Comment: What happened when you found a common denominator?

Comment: How many singularities can a function have at the origin?

Comment: You've already asked this exact question. You know full well this is not cool.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\frac z {\sin z} $ and $\frac {\sin z - z} {z^2}$ have removable singularities at zero. (If you are not allowed to use them as "known facts" then prove them). Then your original problem becomes easy.